# Distinguish between fast to slow mouse wheeling

Tags: java, mouse, awt

To improve user experience on my application, id like to distinguish between user's diffrent mouse wheeling speed and quantity and act accordingly to improve my GUI user freindlyness, how do i analyse it?

Comment: Which framework are you using to interact with the mouse?  Swing?  AWT?  GWT (i.e. not actually Java but JavaScript)?  Something else?

Comment: im using java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener; should i be using a diffrent one?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with MouseWheelListener, as long as your app is written in AWT or Swing.  Indeed, that's the preferred way AFAIK.

Comment: Measure the time between mouse wheel events.  The shorter the time between, the faster the user is turning the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert Harvey makes a good suggestion in the comments, but it doesn't go far enough.  The MouseWheelEvent passed to [MouseWheelListener.mouseWheelMoved](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseWheelListener.html#mouseWheelMoved%28java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent%29) contains a few properties that you should take into consideration beyond the time between events.  Specifically:

- The number of clicks, as returned from [MouseWheelEvent.getPreciseWheelRotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseWheelEvent.html#getPreciseWheelRotation%28%29).
- The amount the user wants to scroll per click, as returned by [MouseWheelEvent.getScrollAmount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseWheelEvent.html#getScrollAmount%28%29).  Note that, unless [MouseWheelEvent.getScrollType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseWheelEvent.html#getScrollType%28%29).  Unless this method returns MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL, MouseWheelEvent.getScrollAmount returns an undefined value.

The first of these methods, MouseWheelEvent.getPreciseWheelRotation, returns the number of clicks that the user rotated the mouse, taking high-resolution mice and trackpads into account.  The higher the absolute value of this number, the more quickly the user was scrolling the mouse.

The second of these methods, MouseWheelEvent.getScrollAmount, tells the system setting that the user's operating system uses for scroll speed.  Using the Windows Control Panel or a similar tool on other platforms, the user can set how quickly the scroll wheel affects change in the interface.  If the user has set a very fast scroll wheel, you should probably count a medium-speed scroll to be the same as a very fast scroll on another platform.  The user asked for things to scroll more quickly, so your app should respect that.

And of course, you should keep the time of the last scroll event (you can use [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) or [System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) to measure time deltas), and shorter intervals between scroll events typically mean faster scrolling.  One possible solution is to keep track of the total number of clicks the user moves the mouse over some constant period of time, say 0.1 or 0.05 seconds, and base the interaction on the accumulated number of scroll wheel clicks rather than the number of clicks that occur in each event.

Comment: Thanks, what is the suggested formula of a nice scroll handling function that depend on variable x which is the number of clicks per o.1 seconds? like how much dpi should i scroll per 0.1 seconds depends on how much clicks were made at that period by the user? if you add an answer to that, your answer will be just perfect

Comment: @OfekRon I have two answers to your question.  First, you shouldn't scroll content yourself - you should use a built-in control to do that for you (an example would be [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) for Swing).  The people who developed Swing put a lot of work into getting scrolling right.  Second, if you aren't scrolling content, the rate of scrolling depends on your app.  For instance, if you're writing a game where the user can use the scroll wheel to jump, then you should probably try a couple different jump heights and pick the best.